Can't deploy my next portfolio due to import issues in vercel, it runs fine in local

Failed to compile.
./src/components/main/Header.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../styles/component_styles/Header.scss'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/layout.tsx
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1


I'm trying to deploy a portfolio I just made, but when i try to deploy it on vercel, it gives the error above, even when my local "npm run build" into "npm start" works fine, and also the "npm run dev" runs fine as well, I'm kind of a beginner so this is my first deploy of a next.js project, and the thing I'm thinking is that the issue is regarding vercel identifying my project folder, since i used the "add src directory" option when creating the project.
If you can help me I'd appreciate, I saw some questions like mine but none had a answer yet, nor a fix that worked for me.
